# Not able to run ros2 node

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed ros2(crystal) in the same machine having ros(melodic). I changed my .bashrc script also as shown below

```
source /opt/ros/crystal/setup.bash
source /home/deepan/ros2_install/ros2-crystal-20190408-linux-bionic-arm64/ros2-linux/setup.bash
```

But when  I try to start a ros2 node(ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker), I am getting the below error.

```
Failed to load entry point 'launch': No module named 'rclpy._rclpy'
Failed to load entry point 'start': No module named 'rclpy._rclpy'
Failed to load entry point 'status': No module named 'rclpy._rclpy'
Failed to load entry point 'stop': No module named 'rclpy._rclpy'
Failed to load entry point 'get': No module named 'rclpy._rclpy'
Failed to load entry point 'list': No module named 'rclpy._rclpy'
Failed to load entry point 'nodes': No module named 'rclpy._rclpy'
Failed to load entry point 'set': No module named 'rclpy._rclpy'
Failed to load entry point 'info': No module named 'rclpy._rclpy'
Failed to load entry point 'list': No module named 'rclpy._rclpy'
Failed to load entry point 'delete': No module named 'rclpy._rclpy'
Failed to load entry point 'get': No module named 'rclpy._rclpy'
Failed to load entry point 'list': No module named 'rclpy._rclpy'
Failed to load entry point 'set': No module named 'rclpy._rclpy'
Failed to load entry point 'generate_policy': No module named 'rclpy._rclpy'
Failed to load entry point 'call': No module named 'rclpy._rclpy'
Failed to load entry point 'list': No module named 'rclpy._rclpy'
Failed to load entry point 'delay': No module named 'rclpy._rclpy'
Failed to load entry point 'echo': No module named 'rclpy._rclpy'
Failed to load entry point 'hz': No module named 'rclpy._rclpy'
Failed to load entry point 'info': No module named 'rclpy._rclpy'
Failed to load entry point 'list': No module named 'rclpy._rclpy'
Failed to load entry point 'pub': No module named 'rclpy._rclpy'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/deepan/ros2_install/ros2-crystal-20190408-linux-bionic-arm64/ros2-linux/bin/ros2", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('ros2cli==0.6.3', 'console_scripts', 'ros2')()
  File "/home/deepan/ros2_install/ros2-crystal-20190408-linux-bionic-arm64/ros2-linux/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ros2cli/cli.py", line 69, in main
    rc = extension.main(parser=parser, args=args)
  File "/home/deepan/ros2_install/ros2-crystal-20190408-linux-bionic-arm64/ros2-linux/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ros2run/command/run.py", line 72, in main
    return run_executable(path=path, argv=args.argv, prefix=prefix)
  File "/home/deepan/ros2_install/ros2-crystal-20190408-linux-bionic-arm64/ros2-linux/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ros2run/api/__init__.py", line 61, in run_executable
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 729, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1364, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/home/deepan/ros2_install/ros2-crystal-20190408-linux-bionic-arm64/ros2-linux/lib/demo_nodes_cpp/talker'
```

Does anyone faced the same issue? If so, please help me with this. Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/326690/not-able-to-run-ros2-node/) by [Deepan](https://answers.ros.org/users/43229/deepan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2019-06-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> ros2-crystal-20190408-linux-bionic-arm64
> ```

and

> ```
> OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
> ```

is your system an ARM8 system in 64bit mode? What is the output of `uname -a`?

Also:

> ```
> source /opt/ros/crystal/setup.bash
> ```

```
source /home/deepan/ros2_install/ros2-crystal-20190408-linux-bionic-arm64/ros2-linux/setup.bash
```

why are you mixing Debian packages with the Linux archives?

---

Edit:

> My system is not arm.

obvious, but you should download the correct binaries for your architecture.

> > why are you mixing Debian packages with the Linux archives?
>
> I just want to check this way. Anyway Iam using Debian Package only.
>
> Can you please suggest me which one is better? either using debian package or linux archives?

If you're just starting, I'd install the Debian packages. They're automatically updated for you and your installation is managed by the system's package manager.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Deepan](https://answers.ros.org/users/43229/deepan/) on 2019-06-23**:
ya..you are right.. I downloaded the wrong package. My system is not  arm.

why are you mixing Debian packages with the Linux archives?
I just want to check this way. Anyway Iam using Debian Package only.

Can you please suggest me which one is better? either using debian package or linux archives? Thank you